# undefined reference xTaskCreate(),vTaskDelay() FreeRTOS stm32 with ARM_CM4F

Tags: c

22:24:01 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project FreeRTOS_tutoeial ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
arm-atollic-eabi-gcc -o FreeRTOS_tutoeial.elf Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\misc.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_adc.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_can.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_crc.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_cryp.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_cryp_aes.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_cryp_des.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_cryp_tdes.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_dac.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_dbgmcu.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_dcmi.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_dma.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_exti.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_flash.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_fsmc.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_gpio.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_hash.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_hash_md5.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_hash_sha1.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_i2c.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_iwdg.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_pwr.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_rcc.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_rng.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_rtc.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_sdio.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_spi.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_syscfg.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_tim.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_usart.o Libraries\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src\stm32f4xx_wwdg.o src\main.o src\startup_stm32f40xx.o src\stm32f4xx_it.o src\syscalls.o src\system_stm32f4xx.o src\tiny_printf.o -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -T../stm32f4_flash.ld -specs=nosys.specs -static -Wl,-cref,-u,Reset_Handler -Wl,-Map=FreeRTOS_tutoeial.map -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--defsym=malloc_getpagesize_P=0x80 -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group -specs=nano.specs
src\main.o: In function `mytask1': main.c:(.text.mytask1+0x12): undefined reference to` vTaskDelay'
src\main.o: In function `main': main.c:(.text.startup.main+0x10): undefined reference to` xTaskCreate'
main.c:(.text.startup.main+0x14): undefined reference to `vTaskStartScheduler'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

22:24:02 Build Finished (took 556ms)

Comment: i have add the header file

Comment: "FreeRTOS.h","FreeRTOSconfig.h","task.h" even though i have check the config value it is correct

Comment: did you link the corresponding library?

Comment: @Chase there is no library.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `.h` files does not add the corresponding `.c` files.

You need to add to the project all the freeRTOS `.c` files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, some freeRTOS files were missing.
So I downloaded the needed files from the freeRTOS [Github repository](https://github.com/maniacbug/FreeRTOS/), and it worked.